# In AngularJS, why can't I specify the image width and height alongside the src?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS to display an image. I'd like to specify the height and width as well so the layout of hte page doesn't shift after the image is loaded. But even when I specify the height and width, the page still shifts, as if the image dimensions are not being updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
<img class="photo" data-ng-src="{{ media_list.url }}" height="{{ media_list.height }}" width="{{ media_list.width }}" />
```

Similarly, when I use inline CSS:

```
<img class="photo" data-ng-src="{{ media_list.url }}" data-ng-style="height:{{ media_list.height }}px; width:{{ media_list.width }}px;" />
```

The rendered result is:

```
<img class="photo" style="height:684px; width:1024;" alt="" data-ng-src="http://server/thumbs/Eryy6aARw-1024-1024.jpg"/?
```

Comment: what are values that show up in live markup?

Comment: `width` and `height` attributes are deprecated in HTML5. Some browsers ignore them. *cough* IE11 *cough*

Comment: I am not sure that ANY version of IE will render height and width correctly, use `ng-style`...

Comment: 'width and height attributes are deprecated in HTML5.' - [what](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-dim-width)?

Comment: @ensnare Is that possible to use `ng-cloak` on that img, or the whole section containing it?

Comment: @raina77ow I see you updated your comment. Cloaking the image won't work (in fact, we need the exact opposite of ng-cloak here), but the concept of using it on the container is the only reasonable solution I could think of as well. At least before we see some more code.

Answer (score 5):

Images are not meant to be used as building blocks, especially in Angular. The image is in the DOM before Angular is ready. That's where the jump comes from. The width/height values are not parsed the moment you open the page, but when Angular and the appropriate controller are ready. Your code would work if you hard-coded the values, but that's not the solution.

Without seeing your code, it's hard to give a good answer, but try showing the whole part of your view where the image is only after the scope and scope values are ready by using something like `ng-show="media_list"` on the container element. This is what I mean:

```
<div id="container" data-ng-show="media_list">
    <!-- other stuff here -->
    <img class="photo" data-ng-src="{{ media_list.url }}" height="{{ media_list.height }}" width="{{ media_list.width }}" />
    <!-- other stuff here -->
</div>
```

The `ng-show` directive would cause the whole block to be invisible until the value is truthy (maybe even use `ng-cloak` instead). You need to figure out where to use this (obviously, using it on the image itself, would cause the jump) - what elements would it make sense to group together and show after the scope is ready.